# Redirect input from another command in windows batch files

Tags: redirect, input, batch-file

In linux I can do something like this:

```
mysql -u user -p=pass somedb <(echo "create database foo;")
```

How can I do that with windows batch scripts?

Basically, I want to make a batch file that runs a sql script without having to keep the script in a separate file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way is to echo  the SQL commands into a file, run the mysql command with option to include the SQL file, and then remove the file (if you really don't want it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
echo create database foo;|mysql ...
```

just fine, but for multiple lines you really want to make a temporary file you just pass to MySQL to read.